# what data type a pandas column should be for BQ to detect it as a json type?

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a pandas data frame with a column that has the result of the "json.dumps()" function in python.
When I'm trying to append this to a table in BQ using "pandas_gbq.to_gbq()" it throws a json type error.
The json dumps in python is producing a json string and not json data type as such.
I've tried multiple options like generating the schema of the table and then applying it or using "client.load_table_from_dataframe()" but all the time BQ sees the column as a string.

So I want the column from pandas to be detected as JSON type by google big query.
Is there a way for this please?

SAMPLE CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
    
d = {'id': [1,2,3], 'nestedJson': [{'k1':1, 'k2':2}, {'k1':3, 'k2':4}, {'k1':5, 'k2':6}]}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**option 1:**

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df , TABLE_id, project_id=Projectname,
                  if_exists='append')
```

**option 2 :**

```
client = bigquery.Client(project=Projectname)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True,
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND"
)
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df , TABLE_id, job_config=job_config)
job.result()
```

ERROR :

```
GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Unsupported field type: JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code smoothly, maybe check you lib version? Mine is `google-cloud-bigquery 3.10.0`

BTW, you can update your BQ table by using `bq.load_table_from_json`; `bq.SourceFormat='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'`